# Software Updater (update-manager) not working in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, dpkg, update-manager

I am currently unable to run Software Updater. When run from the gui interface it immediately returns and provides no additional information. I get the following error output when running from the terminal:

```
user@comp:~$ update-manager
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/update-manager", line 118, in <module>
    app.start_update()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/UpdateManager.py", line 221, in start_update
    update_backend = get_backend(self, InstallBackend.ACTION_UPDATE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/backend/__init__.py", line 365, in get_backend
    raise Exception("No working backend found, please try installing "
Exception: No working backend found, please try installing aptdaemon or synaptic
```

When I attempt to install synaptic (sudo apt-get install synaptic) I get the following output and update-manager fails as above:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libept1.6.0 libxapian30
Suggested packages:
  xapian-tools dwww menu deborphan apt-xapian-index tasksel
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libept1.6.0 libxapian30 synaptic
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 117 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 1,362 kB of archives.
After this operation, 6,346 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://do.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libept1.6.0 amd64 1.1+nmu3ubuntu3 [79.6 kB]
Get:2 http://do.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libxapian30 amd64 1.4.14-2 [661 kB]
Get:3 http://do.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 synaptic amd64 0.84.6ubuntu5 [622 kB]
Fetched 1,362 kB in 5s (293 kB/s) 
/bin/sh: 1: /usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure: not found
Setting up install-info (6.7.0.dfsg.2-5) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/install-info.postinst: 32: update-info-dir: not found
dpkg: error processing package install-info (--configure):
 installed install-info package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 install-info
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When attempting to install aptdaemon (sudo apt-get install aptdaemon) it produces the following output and update-manager fails as above:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
aptdaemon is already the newest version (1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu32.2).
aptdaemon set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 117 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
/bin/sh: 1: /usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure: not found
Setting up install-info (6.7.0.dfsg.2-5) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/install-info.postinst: 32: update-info-dir: not found
dpkg: error processing package install-info (--configure):
 installed install-info package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 install-info
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I recently uppgraded my laptop (Dell Inspiron 15R - to 16 gb RAM and a 1TB SSD that I duplicated from a 1TB HDD. Everything else seems to be working fine.

Can anyone offer any suggestions on how to fix or replace update-manager? Is there something that I can run to check the entire system and detect/fix broken commands?

Thank you,
Claude

Comment: The missing `/usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure` command is a problem. It comes from the `debconf` package, which may be missing or broken. If you `dpkg -l debconf` is it shown as installed? How did you copy the disk from HDD to SSD? Perhaps something was missed?

Comment: I used clonezilla to copy from HDD to SSD. Prior to the move, I had a problem with Network Manager when running off the HDD and WiFi stopped working. I temporarily moved to another smaller drive and installed Ubuntu 20.04. After doing so I had some minor issues on the fresh install with some of the applications I use for Photo, Audio, and Video processing. However, the fresh install solved the problems  with Network Manager.

Comment: When my 1 TB SSD arrived I used clonezilla to copy from my original 1TB HDD. I was then able to reinstall Network Manager. I found a couple of days later that Update Manager had stopped working, hence my current problem.

Comment: Results of [dpkg -l debconf]

dpkg -l debconf
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-======================================
ii  debconf        1.5.73       all          Debian configuration management system